# Setting html elements to null or whitespace is causing field displacement

Tags: jquery, html

Using Bootstrap 4 and jQuery to update my HTML paragraphs.

```
$("#product-unit-price").html(UnitPrice);
```

[Here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/kbrfuller/pen/gOYqrKO). I have purposely set my second field to `""`. The 3rd and 4th fields on the screen are displaced (moved up) because of the 2nd field being `""`.

To resolve the displacement, I now set the UnitPrice to `"&*nbsp;"` (`*` added for display purpose)

This eliminates the displacement issue, but I would still like to know the reason for the displacement in the first place and why I can't I assign `UnitPrice` to `""` or `" "`?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding what the issue is. Can you elaborate, maybe with an image of the problem and the desired outcome? Also you'll need to post a [mcve] in your question, not on a third party site.

Comment: When a html element has no content it's size collapses to 0. Probably the easiest fix is to restructure the html. As is, you basically have a column for the labels and a column for the values. Instead, have one column that contains both. Have 4 divs. Then in each div place the label and value. The label always have content. So emply values won't shift the position of other values.

Comment: He's having a hard time because he has a block element (p) that is collapsing vertically  when he is putting a space in it, and he doesn't understand why.

Comment: @Kruddock Rather than go into why block elements with collapse when empty, and how block elements trim whitespace, I would suggest that you look at the bootstrap documentation on how to build a form and use that https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: Robert.  Thanks for your comment.  So, unless I explicitly give those paragraphs a height, or a min-height they will collapse if the content is empty.

Comment: That is correct, but I would still rebuild your forms using form-groups and either readonly (my preference) or readonly plaintext controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your current HTML structure, this behaviour is expected. It is happening because your `options-field-title` and `options-ajax-field` are two different container and by any chance if any of the field value is empty then it doesn't render anything causing this behaviour. (Since `Pack Unit` is empty, `Price/Qty` starts just after where `Quantity` ends).

To Resolve this issue either you can re-structure your HTML to make sure the title & values are in 1 line.

Something similar like below

```html
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;">
   <p>Quantity</p>
   <p id="product-qty"></p>
</div>
```

OR give them a fix height, so that even if there is no value it won't look different

**Height Approach**

```css
.options-field-title > p, .options-ajax-field > p {
   height: 20px;
}
```